# Handle priority between two journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am struggling to find the right solution for the following requirement:

I have a target to build and reach out with an email communication; people in this target can either have purchased product X or product Y, or both. Now, people who have purchased product X will receive a specific email, while people who receive product Y will receive another.

Thing is, if someone has purchased product X and then also purchases product Y, must receive both communications. The two communications must be sent at the least 7 days apart from each other, and, in case there's an overlap (purchased both in less than 7 days) product X must have the priority.

Not sure if I've been clear.

I think that a good start would be to split the target in two different sub-target DEs, X purchasers and Y purchasers, and have two separate journeys. But I'm not sure how I should handle priority/overlap between the two of them.

I'm not really used in finding and designing functional solutions so I'm having a little hard time here.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try to use Exit Conditions (exit X journey if Y product was bought for instance) in your journeys to handle this ?

Comment: Is Automation Studio off the table as an option?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one journey using a Decision Split. You would of course need this data available as a data attribute and have to add this in Contact Builder in Data Designer so that you can use Contact Data as opposed to Journey Data. Journey path could use the following logic in the Decision Split:

- Path 1: Purchased X and Y - Send email X, wait 7 days, send email Y
- Path 2: Purchased X and not Y - Send email X, wait 7 days, another decision split to check if purchased Y.
- Path 2a: If not purchased Y then continue journey
- Path 2b: If purchased Y then send email Y
- Path 3: If purchased Y but not X, send email Y
- Path 4: Skip email sends if not purchased X or Y

Comment: Yep, but there's a catch: a contact should only enter once in the journey, FOR EACH PRODUCT PURCHASE. That means I can't use the no re-entry option, since it might enter for product X and never enter again when product Y is purchased, nor the re-entry anytime, since it would keep entering the journey and receiving emails each time he buys product X/Y.

Comment: Add an update data activity in the journey if either product email is sent and use that as part of the entry filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one global DE containing all purchases and filter each Journey with the purchase type or pre-split purchases by type into two DEs. Not a real difference here.

You should create a non-reentering journey triggered by the purchase of a X product, which sends the X email. Then wait for 7 days, and if the Y product was bought during this 7 days, send the Y email.

You should also create another non-reentering journey triggered by the purchase of a Y product, whose duty is to send the Y email. The entry of this journey is filtered (or use an exit condition), in order to exclude customers who bought the X product (maybe less than 7 days ago).

Does this fit your use-case ?